# AngularJS bind clicking instead of ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was looking at AngularJs and have a question, this is my directive:

```
myApp.directive("enter", function(){
return{
    restrict: 'A',
    scope:{},
    controller: function($scope){
        $scope.logSomething=function(somevalue){
            console.log(somevalue+" is logged");
        }
    },
    template: '<input type="text" ng-model="myModel">'+
              '<div ng-click="logSomething(myModel)">click me</div>'
}
})
```

This works, but my question is how can I do the same thing using **bind clicking** instead of **ng-click** directive? Not that it is better(maybe?), but for curiosity

it should be including something like this but couldn't get the big picture:

```
 function(scope, element, attrs){
    element.bind("click", function(){
        scope.$apply(attrs.enter);
    })
```

Comment: Use link:function(scope, element, attrs){
    element.bind("click", function(){
        scope.$apply(attrs.enter);
    })

Comment: @Codezilla what about template?

Comment: Right. Sorry. So element is not what we exactly want. You can access the target div using jquery. Not ideal. Or you can implement another directive over the target div.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this one:

```
myApp.directive("enter", function(){
  return{
    restrict: 'A',
    scope:{},
    controller: function($scope){
        $scope.logSomething=function(somevalue){
            console.log(somevalue+" is logged");
        }
    },
    template: '<input type="text" ng-model="myModel">'+
              '<div button>click me</div>'
}
});

myApp.directive("button", function(){   
  return{
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope , element){
       element.bind("click", function(e){
          scope.logSomething( scope.myModel );
       });
    }
}
});
```

Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/RCcrs5?p=preview

Comment: tnx so we need 2 directives for that? i was wondering if thats possible doing everything in same directive

Comment: @Spring Seems like it is not a best practice to put such a different functonalities together in a one directive.. Definitely it will be non reusable. You can try another syntax if you like: http://plnkr.co/edit/arbMYg

Comment: As suggest in the comments, you can also access the div in a jQuery way (for instance, `element.children('div').bind(...)`). But that's a bad idea, because only one directive here is clearly mixing of concerns.

Comment: @Cherniv if I put that "<div button>click me</div>" in html instead of directive is that still ok? without changing anything else

Comment: @Cherniv and also why we use function(e) but not function(scope)

Comment: @Spring `<div button>` will work if it will sit in the same `scope` with the `input` , like here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Wq77ll?p=preview

Comment: @Spring and we're using `function(e)` because it is a `click` event handler , handlers always get the `Event` object which they're waiting to catch (or "listens" to)

Comment: @Cherniv I see, but how do we know <div button> sit in same scope with input? because the second directive is concanated to first directive in your example?

Comment: @Spring they're both in the same scope just if you're not defining private scope in your "enter" directory like this: `scope:{}`

Comment: @Spring sorry , directive , not directory

Comment: @Cherniv thx, I also noticed in ur examples you dont use <div enter="logSomething()"> but just <div enter>, I also see thats eneough for this case, but I remember sometimes I needed to declare the previous way, any ideas?

Comment: @Cherniv Great, pieces start falling int their place now, so scope is actualy nothing but an array?

Comment: @Spring it is more like `Object` with some built-in methods

Comment: Angular is so powerful!

Answer (score 3):

As you pointed out, you can simply use `element.bind`:

```
myApp.directive(
    'clickMe',
    function () {
        return {
            template : '<div>Click me !</div>',
            replace : true,
            link : function (scope, element) {
                element.bind('click', function ()
                {
                    alert('Clicked !');
                });
            },
        };
    }
);
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Blackhole/Exr9J/)</kbd>

But of course, in your case, you **must** use `ngClick` instead.

Comment: tnx, but why I "must" use ng-click? also I cant see the input field in your example?

Comment: This directive is a "subdirective", which only replaces the `div` in the directive you've shown. [Cherniv](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1206613/cherniv) has given a more complete example.
You must use `ngClick` because this is a basic function of AngularJS. There is no point in trying to reimplement an already existent functionality.